# Removing Unnecessary CSS Files

Tags: 7, theming

I am in the process of optimizing my Drupal site by removing unnecessary css files.

Running an audit I have found that `/misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.css`, `/misc/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css` and `/misc/ui/jquery.ui.slider.css` are relatively large but are never called.

I have tried removing them in my template.php file with the following but they still remain. How can I unset them?

```
unset($css[DRUPAL_ROOT.'/misc/ui/jquery.ui.slider.css']);
unset($css[DRUPAL_ROOT.'/misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.css']);
unset($css[DRUPAL_ROOT.'/misc/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`hook_ccs_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7)

```
function yourmodule_css_alter(&$css) {

  unset($css['misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.css']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way in Drupal 7 using **YOUR_THEME_css_alter()** is

```
    function YOUR_THEME_css_alter(&$css) {
    // Remove Drupal core css 
        $exclude = array( //confirm path
            'misc/ui/jquery.ui.slider.css' => FALSE,
            'misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.css' => FALSE,
            'misc/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css' => FALSE,
            // Also you can remove contrib module CSS 
            drupal_get_path('module', 'views') . '/css/views.css' => FALSE,);
        $css = array_diff_key($css, $exclude);
    }
```