Avoid serving unused core files
I analyzed my Drupal website using Chrome's Code Coverage feature. I noticed that there are a lot of core files loaded (CSS and JS) which aren't used at all, for example:



Resource
Unused




/core/modules/system/css/components/system-status-counter.css
100%


/core/modules/system/css/components/system-status-report-counters.css
100%


/core/modules/system/css/components/system-status-report-general-info.css
100%


/core/modules/system/css/components/nowrap.module.css
100%


/core/modules/system/css/components/item-list.module.css
100%


etc...
100%



Is there a way to avoid serving these files if they are not needed on a particular page?

Chrome's code coverage is worthless for dynamic sites. Ignore it. IMHO only useful for fully static sites and onepagers. IMHO pre-cached assets are way more important and perfomant.

It also seems to consider performance only from the browser's point-of-view. The server performance that should check each CSS file before attaching them to the page is not considered. (That makes me think that, as @Hudri said, it is just helpful for static sites, where no PHP is involved.)

@Hudri does that mean all these core CSS files are required to render my page? For example the system-status-counter.css, why would that be required on every page of my website?

No, just that you might be using the wrong tool, and perhaps the wrong thought process, for measuring performance. You’re already using a heavy-ish CMS, on top of PHP no less (not exactly known for its speed), so you’ve already surrendered a lot in terms of potential performance before you even create your first node. With that in mind, Is optimising a few lines of CSS really a good use of one’s time? Generally people think “no”, and spend their time chasing bigger fish.

This was asked 13 years ago in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869433/drupal-remove-unused-css and 10 years ago in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/117749/removing-unnecessary-css-files

Alot of comments on your question but just to give an answer to it. You can use the library-override to remove css/js from other libraries
https://www.drupal.org/node/2497313

That's the first answer/comment that actually answers the question. Thank you!
